Formula for spherical co-ordinates from given zenith
I've got some spherical co-ordinates with respect to a specified zenith (I need to pick an arbitrary azimuth direction), and I'd like to convert them to cartesian (or spherical co-ordinates with respect to the cartesian basis is good enough). The standard formulation for converting spherical to cartesian seems to assume that they are relative to the cartesian basis; I can't find a formulation for a specified zenith basis.
Currently I'm using a quite slow process:

Convert the zenith to spherical co-ordinates with respect to the cartesian basis
Increase elevation by pi/2
Convert this back to cartesian to get an arbitrary azimuth axis
Use a rotation matrix to rotate the zenith about the azimuth axis by the spherical elevation
Use a rotation matrix to rotate the elevated zenith about the zenith's original direction by the spherical azimuth

I've been thinking about maybe using the zenith to define a plane with the point 0,0,0 and the zenith as normal, then finding an arbitrary point on that plane to use as azimuth axis, but this still leaves me with two rotation matrix multiplications after that which I'm keen to simplify.
To be additionally specific, I've set my cartesian basis as left-hand, Y-up. Therefore I'm using
$$
x = r\ cos(elevation) * cos(azimuth)
$$$$
y = r\ sin(elevation)
$$$$
z = r\ cos(elevation) * sin(azimuth)
$$
as my conversion from spherical to cartesian currently, so this is where I need to account for the basis.
Is there a simple or standard formulation for changing the basis or converting to cartesian for spherical co-ordinates?
